# How do I convert np.uint8 into a format usable by PIL.Image?

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library, luxonis

I am trying to combine my computer vision code with existing code from DepthAI(this is the code that actually retrieves each frame from the camera) in order to analyze a depth map image to determine obstacles.
The issue I am running into is that each frame of video from the DepthAI code seems to be in the form of 'np.uint8'.
My computer vision code uses PIL.Image, and I was testing it previously using only .png images. Now that I am integrating the code together, I can't seem to get the DepthAI-retrieved-frames to work with the PIL.Image functions.
The code boxed in `#` tries to reshape the np.uint8 array into a common image resolution (1024x750) but the output image is nonsense. I just want to analyze the colormap image so I can pass this class and graduate :( Does anyone know how to go from np.uint8 to a format compatible with Image?

```
import cv2
import depthai as dai
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image


    q = device.getOutputQueue(name="disparity", maxSize=4, blocking=False)

    while True:
        inDisparity = q.get()  # blocking call, will wait until a new data has arrived
        frame = inDisparity.getFrame()
        # Normalization for better visualization
        frame = (frame * (255 / depth.initialConfig.getMaxDisparity())).astype(np.uint8) #this is where the frame is made into np.uint8

        cv2.imshow("disparity", frame)                  # the resulting images from disparity look correct

        frame = cv2.applyColorMap(frame, cv2.COLORMAP_JET)
        cv2.imshow("disparity_color", frame).       # the resulting image from the colormap looks correct

        #now trying to get the frame to work with PIL.Image
 #####################################################
        reshapedFrame = np.reshape(frame, (750,1024))#
        im = Image.fromarray(reshapedFrame)          #  
        im.show()                                    #
######################################################

        if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
            break
```

[image: cv2.show() output of disparity and corresponding color map]

[image: output from reshaped np.uint, nonsense!]

Comment: Please ensure your code is a [mcve]. If you are having trouble making a **PIL Image** from a Numpy array, just show code that creates a Numpy array similar to the one you are having trouble with, using `np.full()` or similar, and try to make your image and show the error. Else you are looking for someone who knows DepthAI and OpenCV and Numpy and PIL and has time to help.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the grayscale [mode](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes) in [`fromarray`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.fromarray):

```
im = Image.fromarray(reshapedFrame, 'L')
```

Answer (score 0):

Deleting all the code in the box and replacing with `pil_image = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(frame))` solved the issue. Just had to specify the kind of data that was in the array I reckon.